# SAP UI5 Mock Server - How to generate Data for Navigation/Associations

Tags: odata, sapui5

Given I have a below relationship.

Product Category (1) ---- Products(*)

I want to retrieve the products based on a category.
My JSON Data is as follows:

```
  {
    "catergory": "A1",
    "Category_Name": "ABC",
    "Products": [
                    {
                        "ProductId":"123",
                        "ProductCategory" : "A1",
                        "Description":"Example Desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "ProductId":"123",
                        "ProductCategory" : "A1",
                        "Description":"Example Desc"
                    }
                ]
    }
```

Whenever I try to generate data using mockserver, the products array comes up as empty with a **"__deferred"** parameter.
I am sure the metadata is correct since the actual server call gives me the data in correct format.

This is my mockServer instance.

```
sUrl = "http://mockData/";
                jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.util.MockServer");
                this.oMockServer = new sap.ui.core.util.MockServer({
                    rootUri: sUrl
                });
                this.oMockServer.simulate("model/metadata.xml", "model/");
                this.oMockServer.start();

                var oModel = new ODataModel(sUrl, true);
            oModel.setCountSupported(false);
            oView.setModel(oModel);
            this.setModel(oModel);
```

Below is the service Call

```
var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
        oModel.read("/Category?$expand=Products",{
            success: jQuery.proxy(function(data, response){
                console.log("success");
            },this),
            error: jQuery.proxy(function(oErr){
                console.log("error");
            },this)
        });
```

I hope someone can help me out:)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: are you using $expand=Products?
can put the code where you are calling the mockservice

Comment: no. If I put $expand=Products, it throws an error. I have added the mockServer instantiation and service call in the question. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: got the reason for the error. that was because I wasn't passing a category key in my service call. Also, the data was not getting generated because of the type "Edm.Time". Data does not get generated for this. The error thrown is **Invalid time/Duration value**.The Time format is `PT15H53M11S`

Comment: not exactly, it generates data when i provide a JSON file. I dont want to do that. I just want the data to be generated from the metadata by itself

Comment: @Deepak For generating the mock data out of metadata alone, enable `bGenerateMissingMockData` when calling [`simulate`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.util.MockServer/methods/simulate).